# Properly handling -Inf and Inf labels and points with scale_x_continuous()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to make a gg scatter plot with a variable containing Inf and -Inf values:

```
myDF <- data.frame(ratio = log2(0:6/6:0), intensity = rep(1, 7))
```

This is my ggplot code...

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(myDF, aes(x = ratio, y = intensity)) +
       geom_point()
```

[image]

...which handles the Inf and -Inf points without problem. However, I have two questions:

### Question 1

How do I get access to the labels? They seem to be outside what I can access with `scale_x_continuous`.

```
P + scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(-2.5, 2.5, 0.5))
```

[image]

```
P + scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(-5, 5, 1))
```

[image]

### Question 2

How can I avoid the Inf and -Inf points getting cut-off at the plot edges? I think this is in the right direction, but not quite there:

```
p + scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0.3, 0.3))
```

[image]